# Passing scalac opts to Maven from the command-line or environment

Tags: scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

I'm looking for an unobtrusive way to make `mvn` aware of additional flags I'd like to pass to the `scalac` compiler **via the command-line or environment variables only**.

I'm currently using the [scala-maven-plugin](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html) with a command such as:

```
mvn --show-version --batch-mode --errors compile
```

In this case I want `mvn` to treat the compile stage as if it had been passed flags such as:

```
scalac -encoding utf8 -deprecation -unchecked -Xlint:_ -Werror -Wdead-code -Wunused:_
```

I do **not** want to touch the [project's `pom.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html).  The reason for that in this case is that this is a step in an upstream CI/CD templates repository, so I don't have permission to mess with the Maven configuration of the downstream projects.

It does not appear that this is what `MAVEN_OPTS` is made for, so I'm wondering if there is some alternative to talk to `scalac`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `scala:compile` with `-DaddScalacArgs` allows you to pass additional flags to `scalac`:

Example:

```
mvn \
  --show-version \
  --batch-mode \
  --errors \
  scala:compile \
  -DaddScalacArgs='-unchecked|-deprecation|-explaintypes|-Xfatal-warnings|-Xlint:_'
```

Documentation:

- https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#addScalacArgs
- https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_compile.html

Note that the available options to `scalac` have changed with Scala versions.

You can use:

- `mvn scala:help`
- `scalac -X`
- `scalac -Xlint:help`

To see the underlying version and the available `-X` options.